# What exactly are secondary members acknowledging in replicasets with MongoDB?

Tags: replication, mongodb, nosql

I try to understand the mechanics and behavior of [MongoDB's replica](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/replication-introduction/)-features better. I hope to get some insightful information from someone who is familiar with mongo's internals and behaviour. My aim is to understand Mongo's durability guarantees in a high-availability setup. The data I want to maintain would have unique constraints (by using two unique indexes), to maintain a 1:1 relationship by having two unique values in one doc. Inconsistencies or only partial durability would be fatal for my 1:1 relation and hardly resolvable once happened, especially undetected.

**My question:**

What exactly are secondaries acknowledging in a replica-set setup and using the writeconcern:"majority"?

That only the statement is acknowledged and applied in the secondary or that the whole oplog up until the new statement is applied?

**Explanation of what exactly I am looking for:**

According to their own documentation and some other sources (e.g. Aphyr's try on simulating network-partitions and his [follow-up](https://aphyr.com/posts/322-call-me-maybe-mongodb-stale-reads)) using write-concern "majority" will make sure, that no write will be lost even in partitioning-scenarios and the like. (since I cannot post more than two links, I will not be able to refence mongodb's documenation). Stale reads are acceptable in my use-case.

But one thing that I just cannot figure out from their documentation is, **what exactly is acknowledged on the replicas.**

Replica-Sets are replicated using the oplog (collection of statements that modified data) by distributing them asynchronously. For avoiding a rollback once a failed primary tries to join the cluster with writes, that were not distributed (because of the asynchronous nature), they recommend using the majority-writeconcern (Doc->Replica->Replica Concepts->High Availbilty->Rollback). To my understanding, there is a case, where this cannot be achieved, depending on what exactly is acknowledged.

Let's say we have three instances, (1), (2), (3). One is primary (1,P) and the other two are secondaries (2,S), (3,S).

We are now trying to insert two new rows/docs {1} and {2}. And due to network-instability, instances will be unavailable to each other at some times.

Let's say the replicasets acknowledge single statements from the primary, then the following can happen:

1. instance (3,S) is unavailable, but inserting record {1} will succeed since there are 2 out of 3 available (majority achieved).

*Current state:*

(1,P):{{1}}

(2,S):{{1}}

(3,S):{{}} *unreachable*

2. instance (2,S) becomes unavailable and instance (3,S) happens to be online (not restarted, just online to the others). Meanwhile no asynchronous replication was initiated by the primary. Record {2} is inserted. Majority achieved again (2 out of 3)

*Current state:*

(1,P):{{1},{2}}

(2,S):{{1}} *unreachable*

(3,S):{{2}}

If (1,P) goes down, an election will happen. (2) or (3) will become primary. But that will make the database inconsistent, since the new primary has no knowledge of the other lost doc/row. Now some sort of rollback is bound to happen when the original primary comes online (and thus losing data).

**If** acknowledges are made by applying all latest oplog-entries, then this should not happen. (2,S) would have both entries when acknowledging {2}. And then will also win the election. Data is not lost.

I am well aware that this is unlikely to happen. But if it happens, I don't see how it would even be detected or avoidable unless automatic failover is just disabled.

Comment: Meanwhile I have done some successful research and I have found a presentation that hints that replicas acknowledge applying all operations of the oplog up until the to be acknowledged entry.

https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/replication-internals-life-write-0

It starts at roughly 22:00, the slides of the presentation can be found here:

http://de.slideshare.net/mongodb/replication-internals-the-life-of-a-write

the interesting part starts at slide 11.

I am not sure though, I would like someone with a better understanding to confirm that.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, while the question(s) is(are) rather complex, the answer(s) is(are) pretty simple, albeit a bit lengthy.

### The replication (simplified)

When an operation is saved in the oplog, it does not get distributed to the other members. It gets *pulled* by the replica set members.

A failed member rejoining the replica set will contact the primary and pull the oplog entries it hasn't processed. So it will eventually become consistent.

However, there is a caveat. For performance reasons, the oplog is a capped collection. This means there is limited space available for it. With limited space, you have a limited number of operations which can be written to the oplog. And limited operations reach back only a limited amount of time, since the oldest entries of the oplog will be overwritten when a new entry would exceed the oplogs size limit. The limited time frame is called the replication oplog window.

If member rejoins the cluster and its last operation is older than the oldest entry in the primaries oplog, it becomes stale and needs to have an complete resync of the data.

So in your example, after 3,S went down, 2,S still would happily pull the oplog.
In your example, all three are up for a short amount of time, until 2,S failed. The election now would take place, and since there is no need to change the primary 1,P would still serve in this function.

Now, when 3,S came up within the oplog window, it would simply connect to the primary, pull the oplog, apply the oplog entries to its data set and all lived happily ever after (except for the admin who has to get his back moving to get up 2,S again for double redundancy).

In case 3,S comes up outside the oplog window, you'd have to initialize a full resync by

1. Shutting down the instance of `mongod`
2. Wipe its `dbpath`
3. Restart the instance

Note that if 2,S isn't up and resynced during that procedure, the cluster wouldn't have a majority up and running and hence be unwritable.

### Acknowledgement of operations

With a write concern of `{w:1}`, the primary would acknowledge the query to be

1. Received and
2. syntactically correct since it is
3. Applied to the in memory data set of both the data and the oplog

With a write concern of `{w:1,j:1}`, all of the above applies. Additionally, modifications are written to the journal, making the data guaranteed to be durable - except for the edge case of the journal being damaged.

Keep in mind that operations are written to the journal every [commitIntervalMs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.journal.commitIntervalMs]), 100msecs by default, one third of the configured value with a write concern of `{"w":x, "j":1}`. We will come back to this later.

With the replication process as detailed above, it is sufficient that the `{"w":x, "j":1}` for x > 1 works different, since the primary is then guaranteed to have the latest data of all replica set members: With said write concern, the write to the journal is only acknowledged for the primary.

The replica set is either writable from the clients point of view (the majority of non-hidden, non-delayed members is up) or not. If it is writeable, the primary is guaranteed to have the latest data, and secondaries failing back will either automatically resync from the oplog or need to be fully resynced.

### Edge case for `{w:1}`

There is a special condition, however. With a write concern of `{w:1}` it can happen that a primary about to fail accepted writes which did not make it to the secondaries. When this this machine rejoins the replica set, it will notice that its newest write operation is newer than the oldest of the new primaries oplog it hasn't processed. The instance will then identify all write operations it has accepted but didn't make it to the secondaries, writing them to the `rollback` folder in `dbpath`, up to a limit of 300MB.

Dealing with [rollbacks](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/replica-set-rollbacks/) can be quite tricky, however, it is easy to prevent: set `w > 1`.

**Rule of thumb: Never set `w < 2` unless you can afford to loose data**

### Conclusion

With a write concern of `w<1`, you prevent rollbacks and can be pretty sure that a write operation is durable. It only would not be durable if *all* replica set members the data was supposed to be processed by failed within a time frame of commitIntervalMs, so (for the default values) 100ms in a worst case scenario (all journals are written at the exact same point in time), 50ms in a best case scenario (the journals are shifted by exactly 50ms), giving us an average of 75ms in which *all* affected replica set members had to fail. If that is too much for you, either add more replica set members, lowering the probability that all servers supposed to process the operations fail, or set `j:1`. Still, this applies only *if `w` replica set members fail simultaneously*. With a geographically distributed replica set, the probability for this scenario equals 0 for all practical purposes. And in case of the Zombie Apocalypse happening simultaneously with an invasion by little green aliens, I assume your concerns (no pun intended) will shift.

If write operations are **extremely** important to be written to disk when acknowledged, you still can take the sledgehammer of forcing a file sync before you consider a write operation to be successful.